# Flask working outside of application context despite app being initialised

Tags: python, flask, mysql-python

I am trying to query a simple MySQL DB using MySQLdb in Flask. I have the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import json
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL()

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'dbuser'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'calendar'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)

db = mysql.connect()
cur = db.cursor()
```

When I run this code, I get the following error in the Apache log:

```
RuntimeError: working outside of application context
```

I have verified that I am creating my `app` object before placing any calls to MySQLdb and read a number of pages/docs, but I cannot fathom why my code is failing, as it seems the same as other examples (such as https://codehandbook.org/python-web-application-flask-mysql/ and https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-python-flask-and-mysql--cms-22972)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mysql.connect()](https://github.com/admiralobvious/flask-mysqldb/blob/master/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py#L40) use `current_app` everywhere, so you have to call it inside of application context.

**Method 1: Push an application context temporarily**

```
with app.app_context():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
```

Normally, you needn't create the global object. Instead, you can create `cur` object inside view function.

**Method 2: Call it inside view function**

```
@app.route('/')
def users():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('''SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user''')
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    return str(rv)
```

If you have a bunch of view functions use this object, you can create a before request handler to create it.

**Method 3: Call it in `before_request` function, then you can access `cur` in all the view function directly**

```
@app.before_request
def make_db():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have tried method 3 but now am getting `TypeError: 'Connection' object is not callable` when trying to call `db = mysql.connect()` ? EDIT: option 2 is working for me :)

Comment: I made a mistake, the `mysql.connect` is a property.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
mysql = MySQL()
```

use

```
mysql = MySQL(app)
```

so that your mysql object will be connected to your app.

(You can follow what this means by starting here: [https://github.com/admiralobvious/flask-mysqldb/blob/master/flask_mysqldb/**init**.py#L8](https://github.com/admiralobvious/flask-mysqldb/blob/master/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py#L8))

Answer (score 0):

if you're using
`from flask_mysqldb import MySQL` use. For example, let's call this page app_file.py

```
    app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = "host_ip"
    app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = "your_username"
    app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = "your_pass"
    app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = "your_db"
    app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = "DictCursor"
    with app.app_context():
        db = MySQL(app)
```

Now you can access the variable. Below is an example of calling from a different class. Here I am using blueprint.

```
from app_file.py import db
@yourapi.route("/testUrl")
def testMysql():
    cur = db.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('''select * from user limit 0,10''')
    row_headers=[x[0] for x in cur.description] #this will extract row headers
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    json_data=[]
    for result in rv:
        json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,result)))
    return json.dumps(json_data)
```